# Batch File Console

Tags: batch-file

How Can I hide the console of a running batch file 
the batch is running from a cmd or  start>run

Comment: You need to provide more info. what runs the batch file.

Comment: please give information about whats running it. and what type of batch file it is.

Comment: IF I run the Batch from cmd or double click or start>run not from a software or a development language
(from Windows)

Answer (score 3):

You can try a couple of things:

Schedule it with a user other than you.

or

```
CMD /C START /MIN your.CMD
```

or

This WSH/VBScript will run your batch file in a hidden window:

```
'MyCmd.vbs
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "C:\bin\scripts\MyCmd.cmd"
Return = WshShell.Run(cmd, 0, True)
set WshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your batch file add these lines.

```
@echo off
if not defined PIL (
    set PIL=1
    start /min "" %~0
    exit /b
)

Replace the rest of your batch here
```

If `PIL` is not defined in your batch file then the batch file will restart itself minimized. If `PIL` is defined in your environment then change it to something else. This will restart the batch file with `PIL` defined as `1` and since `PIL` is defined it will skip the restarting section after the file has been restarted.

Answer (score 0):

make a shortcut to the batch then right click and select properties 
now under the general tab there will be a run option click the arrow beside it and select minimized now click apply and ok now start the program and it will run in the  background.

hope i helped you this is pretty much guaranteed to work on any bat file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this software to code .exe apps and it has a command that can do this. The name of the software is Advanced Bat to Exe Converter but it doesn't only convert, you can code and compile them too. Try this coding once you download the program from [here](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/), this should also work with other exe compilers, but I am not sure.

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
color 9e
rem ChangeColor 14 0
rem ChangeColor 14 9
rem PrintBoxAt 6 11 15 60 1
rem PrintBoxAt 11 21 5 40 1
rem printcenter Enter window title: 13 14 9
rem getinput
set w=%result%
rem hidewindow "%w%"
goto menu
```